# How do I rename my TTY terminal?

Tags: centos, ttyusb

I have a Centos 7 server with 48 USB to serial devices plugged into it. Using `udev`, I was able to write a script that creates symlinks in the `/dev` folder that map the `ttyUSBx` devices to corresponding `ttyDy` names, based on the serial number of the device. I then run an instance of `agetty` on the `ttyDy` device files.

The problem is, when I log in from a remote terminal, the `tty` command outputs the name of the *root* `ttyUSB` device, and *not* the `ttyD` symlink I created (also, `ps -e` will output my `ttyUSB` port as the `tty` of the bash shell). Is there a command I can run as part of my `.bashrc`, or an argument sent to login or `agetty` that will allow me to change the name of my `tty` to my static `ttyD` port?

Comment: Try a _hard_ link instead of a symlink.

Comment: I set up the hard link manually, and it looks like that sorted it out. Thanks.

Comment: just be aware that deleting the hard link deletes both nodes.

Answer (score 1):

This was answered already in a comment but I'm going to post it as an answer since the original answerer did not.

You will want to hard link to the device nodes instead of symbolic linking.